# How to insert rows into Mysql database without duplicate?

Tags: c#, mysql, duplicates

When i want to insert a row into my MySql database 4 rows will be inserted instead of 1. Could you help me?

```
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                    string Query = "Insert Into csokolade (márka,ár,darab) values('" + this.Marka_Textbox.Text + "','" + this.Ar_Textbox.Text + "','" + this.Darab_Textbox.Text + "')";
                    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

EDIT: Here is the part of the code that has to insert the row:

```
    try
            {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                con.Open();
                int a = 0;
                string q = "select count(*) from csokolade where márka='" + this.Marka_Textbox.Text + "';";
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(q, con);

                try
                {
                    a = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                if (a == 0)
                {
                    string Query = "Insert Into csokolade (márka,ár,darab) values('" + this.Marka_Textbox.Text + "','" + this.Ar_Textbox.Text + "','" + this.Darab_Textbox.Text + "')";
                    com = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ez a rekord már létezik!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: This code will insert only one record.  Perhaps you're executing this code four times?  Please also note that your code is *highly vulnerable* to **SQL injection attacks**.  You're going to want to look up "parameterized queries" and start using those.

Comment: Show rest of your code where you are calling this insertion block.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with WPF? If not please remove that tag.

Comment: i edited the code, the remaining code does something else

Comment: a trigger in mysql server could solve this problem?